# Passing error parameter as querystring in format.html through render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `create` method much similar to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @contact.save
    # something happen
  else
    format.html { render :index }
  end
end
```

The errors are being rendered with the `:index` page, but I want to pass a parameter like `?error=true` to the URL to handle a few things with JavaScript.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with setting instance variable before rendering page like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @contact.save
    # something happen
  else
    @error = true 
    format.html { render :index }
  end
end
```

Comment: And then use .erb extension on my js file to `if (<%= @error %>)`?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge It won't work for `js.erb` as you have specified `format.html` only.